# Update grouped records with sequence in sql

Tags: sql

I have following structure of data in sql table

```
COL1    COL2    COL2   GRP_ID
A       A       B      100
A       A       B      100
A       A       C      101
A       A       B      100
A       D       E      102
A       D       E      102
F       G       H      103
F       G       H      103
```

i have the code same this one but it is for oracle,  in sql it is not possible to define a function for next value for. How to change this code for sql?

```
CREATE FUNCTION NEXT
      RETURN NUMBER IS
      v_nextval NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      v_nextval := NEW_SEQUENCE.nextval;

      RETURN(v_nextval);
   END;
/

UPDATE EXAMPLE
SET EXAMPLE.GroupID = 
  (  
   SELECT G.GroupID FROM 
   ( 
     SELECT B.Column1, B.Column2, B.Column3, MY_SCHEMA.NEXT() AS GroupID 
     FROM EXAMPLE B 
     GROUP BY B.Column1, B.Column2, B.Column3
   ) G 
   Where G.Column1 = EXAMPLE.Column1 AND G.Column2 = EXAMPLE.Column2 
   AND G.Column3 = EXAMPLE.Column3);

SELECT * 
FROM EXAMPLE
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: i taged it with the sql

Comment: . . SQL is a *language* mostly noted for the difference between different implementations -- Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, DB2, Teradata, BigQuery, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite, and so on are *databases*.

Comment: I've removed th conflicting RDBMS; only tag the RDBMS you are aiming to deploy to.

Answer (score 0):

The `GRP_ID` can be calculated using `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       dense_rank() over (order by col1, col2, col3) as grp_id
from t;
```

If you want to update the value, one method is:

```
update t
    set grp_id = (select count(distinct col1, col2, col3) + 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col1 < t.col1 or
                        (t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 < t.col2) or
                        (t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col3 <= t.col3)
                 );
```

Note that not all database support `count(distinct)` on multiple columns.  In those databases, you can concatenate the values together.

Comment: but i want the grp_id take the number from the sequence function.